# Форма введения числа и вывода факториала

Tags: python, forms, django

Как в django сделать форму введения числа и вывода его факториала после нажатия кнопки? Нужна сама идея.

Пример: вводите в формочку число 5, жмете кнопку "calculate", получаете вывод посчитаного факториала.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать вообще посредством javascript'a, без запросов на сервер.
Но если хотите использовать возможности python/django, то первая идея: форма для ввода числа, кнопка submit, во view принимаем форму, получаем из формы число, считаем факториал числа, возвращаем форму с ответом. Ну это, как Вы попросили, "сама идея".

Comment: Удачи в изучении! Спасибо за принятие ответа!